# Why do some planes have flashing lights within the plane cabin?

Tags: air-travel, aircraft

I took a plane from Hong Kong to Yangon (flight number: [Cathay Dragon KA 250](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cathay%20Dragon%20KA%20250); Airbus A321 (twin-jet) according to [FlightAware](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/HDA250)) and I noticed some flashing lights in the plane cabin throughout the flight. Video: https://youtu.be/3ccvmWNxTu0

Picture with and without the light:

[image]

[image]

Pretty much all segments lighted up at some point during the flight. I couldn't detect any lighting pattern.

Why do some planes have such flashing lights within the plane cabin? It lasted the entire flight.

Comment: It looks more like a malfunction than anything, but the fact that different segments light up makes it quite weird...

Comment: @jcaron pretty much all segments lighted up at some point during the flight. I couldn't detect any lighting pattern.

Comment: If it was a Southwest plane instead of an American Airlines plane, I'd say a flight attendant had probably climbed into the overhead bins one time too many....

Comment: Aircraft model?

Comment: @NeanDerThal  Type

Airbus A321 (twin-jet) according to the FlightAware website when searching for the flight number.

Comment: You ask this like it's a feature...it's not.

Comment: @CGCampbell This is a disappointment.

Answer (score 12):

I am pretty sure the effect you describe is due to equipment malfunction.

Cabin lights are usually dimmed during night take-off and night landing, and on long-haul flights to allow passengers to sleep comfortably. This is normal behaviour. However, flashing lights are not.

Comment: I agree, seen this many times. It is usually due to bad programming of the light settings by maintenance, happens when lights are on dimmed settings.